# Run rails cron job with a life span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

My Rails cron job:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

I only want this triggered when an attribute in MyModel is set to true and stop when it is set to false.

Comment: I'll provide an example ActiveJob shortly.

Answer (score 0):

For triggered when an attribute (e.g. availability) in MyModel set to true and stop if it is set to be false, You need to create a method in `MyModel` like this -

```
  def other_process
    if attr
      MyModel.some_process
      rake "my:rake:task"
      command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
    end
  end

  every 3.hours do
    MyModel.other_process
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Rails Active Job is designed for this very use case.

> Active Job is a framework for declaring jobs and making them run on a variety of queuing backends. These jobs can be everything from regularly scheduled clean-ups, to billing charges, to mailings. Anything that can be chopped up into small units of work and run in parallel, really.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html